# `ref` issue with react-bootstrap elements

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to get the get value selected by a [DropdownButton](http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#btn-dropdowns) with ref='roleType', but whatever I tried fails.

```
    <DropdownButton ref='roleType' bsStyle='link' title='Role' key='1'  bsSize='xsmall'>
      {_items}
    </DropdownButton>
```

I have tried the followings:

```
 React.findDOMNode(this.refs.roleType)
 this.refs.roleType.getDOMNode()
```

Note: I am not sure if it is important or not. The `DropdownButton` is inside a `Panel`, which is inside a `section` of a `div`.

Comment: I guess you pass a function to `onSelect` and get the value from there.

Comment: @FelixKling but why not using a `ref`?

Comment: Because it doesn't look like you can access the value via `ref`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `onSelect` prop of `DropdownButton`, as noted on the [docs](http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#btn-dropdowns).

```
var DropdownButton = ReactBootstrap.DropdownButton;
var MenuItem = ReactBootstrap.MenuItem;

var Hello = React.createClass ({
    getInitialState() { 
        return { key: null }
    },

    onSelect(key) {
        this.setState({ key: key });
    },

    render() {
        var selected = this.state.key ? <p>Selected: {this.state.key}</p> : '';
        return (<div>
        <DropdownButton bsStyle="primary" title="Test" onSelect={this.onSelect}>
          <MenuItem eventKey='1' active={this.state.key==='1'}>Action</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem eventKey='2' active={this.state.key==='2'}>Another action</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem eventKey='3' active={this.state.key==='3'}>Active Item</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem divider />
          <MenuItem eventKey='4' active={this.state.key==='4'}>Separated link</MenuItem>
        </DropdownButton>
        {selected}
        </div>);
    }
});

React.render(<Hello/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Here's a working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/gadr/azm159g4/2/

Comment: but why not using a `ref`?

Comment: `ref` is useful when you need to get the value out of something that **didn't** originate the event. In this case, there's really no point. Also, it seems that it's [not entirely possible](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/303) to interact via `ref`s.